# Why this code for comparison var using javascript not work correct ?

Tags: javascript

Why this code for comparison var using javascript not work correct ?

Normally , this code will be alert `max more than min`

but why when i tested this , it's alert `max less than min`

https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/23270/

```
<script>
function change(){
    var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
    if(max < min)
    {
        alert("max less than min");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("max more than min");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Value returns a string try using parseInt to convert it to a number

Answer (score 0):

DOM `<input>` element values are alway strings, so comparisons are string comparisons. If you want to compare input values as numbers, convert them:

```
if (+max < +min)
```

Of course, you don't know whether the person looking at the page has actually typed in numeric values, so things get a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Should be written as:

```
<script>
function change(){
    var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
    if(max < min)
    {
        alert("max less than min");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("max more than min");
    }
}
</script>
```

Please note the parseInt.  Otherwise you're comparing string values.

Comment: `parseInt()` should probably include the second argument to stipulate the base. Also, we don't know that the values should be limited to integers.

Answer (score 0):

Because they're not interpreted as numbers, for example integers.

I've updated the code and included the [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) function here:
https://jsfiddle.net/fNPvf/23271/

```
<script>
function change(){
    var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
    if(max < min)
    {
        alert("max less than min");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("max more than min");
    }
}
</script>
```

Also note, if you need them to be interpreted as floats, use [parseFloat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) etc.

Answer (score 0):

you have to parse the max and min strings to values using parseFloat (more general case) or parseInt (if you are using integers) ..

So your code can be corrected as follow

```
function change(){
    var min = parseFloat(document.getElementById("min").value);
    var max = parseFloat(document.getElementById("max").value);
    if(max < min)
    {
        alert("max less than min");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("max more than min");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps